# How do I deal with a pine tree infestation?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, tree-care, pines

My pine tree is heavily infested with some kind of white stuff. It looks like some kind of scales or white powder that is covering all the pine needles. Anyone know how to deal with this without cutting down the tree?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As you've already found out, new users can't post photos directly, but if you upload them to a photo sharing site such as imgur.com, flickr.com etc. and post a link, an established user can edit them into your question for you.  Please also see the [about] page and the [faq] for a quick overview of how the site works.  Again, welcome!

Comment: post a closeup picture of the issue, it could be a type of scale or insect

Answer (score 1):

This time of year, are you sure it's not pollen? The pines here just released massive clouds of the stuff. If you brush against them, you end up choking on the stuff.